# Validate biblatex language fields

Tags: biblatex, biber

`biblatex` supports using language codes in the `language` field for an entry (listed as Table 2 in the docs). Is it possible to issue a warning, in case something is not one of the known language codes? For instance, I would have liked to automatically spot the typo in `engglish` in the MWE below.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\usepackage[style=alphabetic,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\bibliography{test}

\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
@techreport{Volpe2000,
 author = {Wolpe, Richard and Nesnas, Issa A. D. and Estlin, Tara and Mutz, Darren and Petras, Richard and Das, Hari},
 date = {2000},
 institution = {Jet Propulsion Laboratory, California Institute of Technology},
 location = {Pasadena, California},
 language = {engglish},
 title = {{CLARAty}: Coupled Layer Architecture for Robotic Autonomy}
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
This is a test~\autocite{Volpe2000}.

\printbibliography{}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What would count as 'known' language code? The ones listed in the `babel` docs, the ones known by `polyglossia`, those languages for which `biblatex` has an `.lbx`?

Comment: @moewe There is a list of languages in the bibtex docs (Table 2). I thought that is the important one?

Comment: That is a reasonable assumption.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you want to test for languages supported by `biblatex`, you can actually test if the bibstring `lang<language>` exists. It exists if and only if the language is listed in Table 2 of the `biblatex` documentation.

Since `language` is a field, we can use the `index` trick to process its values.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[style=alphabetic,backend=biber]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@techreport{Volpe2000,
 author = {Wolpe, Richard and Nesnas, Issa A. D. and Estlin, Tara and Mutz, Darren and Petras, Richard and Das, Hari},
 date = {2000},
 institution = {Jet Propulsion Laboratory, California Institute of Technology},
 location = {Pasadena, California},
 language = {engglish},
 title = {{CLARAty}: Coupled Layer Architecture for Robotic Autonomy}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\makeatletter
\DeclareIndexListFormat{language}{%
  \ifboolexpr{ test {\ifbibstring{#1}} or test {\ifbibstring{lang#1}} }
    {}
    {\blx@warning@noline{Unknown language '#1'
       in 'language' field of\MessageBreak
       '\thefield{entrykey}'}}}

\AtDataInput{\indexlist{language}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
This is a test~\autocite{Volpe2000}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

---

This is not much different from

```
\DeclareListFormat{language}{%
  \usebibmacro{list:delim}{%
    \ifbibstring{#1}
      {\bibxstring{#1}}
      {\ifbibstring{lang#1}
         {\bibxstring{lang#1}}
         {#1}}}%
  \ifbibstring{#1}
    {\bibstring{#1}}
    {\ifbibstring{lang#1}
       {\bibstring{lang#1}}
       {\blx@warning@noline{Unknown language '#1'
          in 'language' field of\MessageBreak
          '\thefield{entrykey}'}%
        #1}}%
  \usebibmacro{list:andothers}}
```

The difference being that with the second solution the warning is only issued if `language` is printed.